# Why do I have excessive hard disk activity after using Kubuntu 14.10 for about 10 minutes?

Tags: hard-drive, kubuntu, 14.10

Even just opening several web pages and checking email for about 10 minutes causes the hard drive light comes on solid and I'm done for ~ 5 min until the light goes out. I have a few years old Dell with 2GB RAM. I'm running Windows Tech Preview 10 on another partition.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you provide the output to `free --human` before and after this happens and `iostat` while it happens?

Comment: total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:               2.0G       1.8G       146M        42M        28M       733M
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.1G       908M
Swap:                  0B         0B         0B

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer and provide the output there as it's pretty unreadable now...

Comment: free --human gives me (this was output during the HDD--I assume--activity):  
Mem:  total=2.0G / used=1.8G / free-144M / shared=5.2M / buffers=30M / cached=1.1G
-/+ buffers/cache:  used=726M / free=1.3G
Swap:  total=3.7G / used=511M / free=3.2G

iostat gives me:

avg-cpu:   %user=24.28    %nice=1.76    %system=4.66   %iowait=23.84    %steal=0.00   %idle=45.46

Device:  
sda              tps=80.82      kB_read/s=8427.46      kB_wrtn/s=1463.08   kB_read=76233013   kB_wrtn=13234696

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and provide the output there because it's pretty unreadable now.  Also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for a while and fixed it as follows:

I run the command `sudo iotop` in the terminal. The output of his command showed that most of the "mysterious" I/O was being performed by the processes updatedb/mlocate and updatedb/locate.

As I understand it, the function of these cron-launched process is to maintain up-to-date an internal linux db, by means of which the system makes the location of files much more efficient.

My solution was to deactivate the execution of this processes by means of the commands

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
sudo chmod -x /etc/cron.daily/locate
```

However, to avoid the degradation of the db for file-location, I periodically execute locate and mlocate at a suitable moment. The following commands make these processes executable again:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/locate
```

Comment: The terminal says:  'sudo:  iotop:  command not found'